# How to find parameters for Granger causality(VAR)?

Tags: statistics, data-mining, var, causality, autoregressive-models

Does anyone know how to find parameters in Granger causality (vector autoregression model)?

I've found how to estimate them, but how do people usually set these parameters up?

Comment: You can follow this material: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/time-series-analysis-python/